# What does it mean isInstance is a 'dynamic equivalent' of instanceof?

Tags: java, class, instanceof

What does it mean 'dynamic equivalent'?

I just wonder what is the purpose of having `this.getClass().isInstance(aClass)` instead of `this instanceof aClass`? Is there a difference?

> Determines if the specified Object is assignment-compatible with the
>   object represented by this Class. This method is the dynamic
>   equivalent of the Java language instanceof operator

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. Not only is the order not the same, but `object instanceof Clazz` must have a class which is known at compile time.  `clazz.isInstance(object)` can take a class which is known at runtime.

There is also subtle difference in that isInstance will auto-box, but instanceof will not.

e.g.

```
10 instanceof Integer // does not compile
Integer.class.isInstance(10) // returns true

Integer i = 10;
if (i instanceof String) // does NOT compile
if (String.class.isInstance(i)) // is false
```

To see the difference I suggest you try to use them.

Note: if you do `object.getClass().getClass()` or `myClass.getClass()` you will just get a `Class` Be careful not to call `getClass()` when you don't need to.

Answer (score 5):

The `instanceof` operator tests to see if an object is an instance of a fixed (static) class; i.e. a class whose name is known at compile time.

The `Class.isInstance` method allows you to test against a dynamic class; i.e. a class that is only known at runtime.

---

> I just wonder what is the purpose of having `this.getClass().isInstance(aClass)` instead of `this instanceof aClass`? Is there a difference?

The purpose of `isInstance` is as above.

The primary difference between those two expressions is:

- in the first one, `aClass` is a *variable* whose value is a `Class` object, and
- in the second one, `aClass` is the *name* of a class: it CANNOT be a variable.